How to Remove Ambiguity?
Consider the following grammar with start variable $S$:
$$
S → SS | AAA | ϵ ,\
A → aA | Aa | b
.$$
Prove that it is ambiguous and then remove its ambiguity. (Terminals are $a$ and $b$.)
Actually, proving that it is ambiguous is easy, for example, one can design two different parse trees for "bbab", but I don't know how to remove the ambiguity.
Thank you for your time.
